# Get permissions and concatenate them in one line

Tags: text-processing

Here is the result of listing the files in a directory.

```
total 4
-rw-r--r-x 1 y_wc y_wc 6828641 dez 24 18:21 file1
-rw-rw-rw- 1 y_wc y_wc 2051577 dez 24 18:13 file2
-rw-rwxr-x 1 y_wc y_wc 1874334 dez 24 18:14 file3
-rw-rwxrwx 1 y_wc y_wc 2902856 dez 24 18:14 file4
```

I'd like to concatenate the permissions in one line by the same order by which they appear. Here permissions exclude the file type. The output should be
`rw-r--r-xrw-rw-rw-rw-rwxr-xrw-rwxrwx`

I'd like solutions using coreutils and, separately, `awk`.

I'm close with the coreutils solution, but I'm unable to get rid of the file type character. Here's what I got

```
ls -l | tail -n+2 | cut -d" " -f1 | tr -d '\n'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` has very poor options for formatting . `stat` has `--printf`  option , to format has you want information about files .

a example :

```
root@linux:~# stat --printf  '%A\n' /etc/passwd /etc
-rw-r--r--
drwxr-xr-x
```

in tour case because you don't the first character

```
root@linux:~# stat --printf  '%A\n' file*  | cut -c2-11 | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is printing the file type.

Comment: The `cut` could be just `cut -c 2-`.

Answer (score 1):

The first character can be removed with `cut -c 2-`

```
ls -l | tail -n+2 | cut -d" " -f1 | cut -c 2- | tr -d '\n'
```